# Can I filter an image client side, Not server side, using PHP GD Library?

Tags: php, javascript, css, image-manipulation, client-side

I use Soundcloud for my tracks.

I'm using their jquery player to place a widget on my new site, as you can see on the top right:

[image: I'm using their jquery player to place a widget on my new site, as you can see on the top right:]

The problem is, the waveform Souncloud provides is a one colour only deal:
[image: Soundcloud waveform only in one colour]

**My goal: To change this waveform PNG from curent colour to black, but client side.**

I know I can change things using PHPs GD library, and I've done this successfully with a  test image on my server using this code:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php
(Search for "IMG_FILTER_BRIGHTNESS")

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng('hello.png');

if($im && imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_BRIGHTNESS, -255))
{
echo 'Image brightness changed.';

imagepng($im, 'hello.png');
imagedestroy($im);
}
else
{
echo 'Image brightness change failed.';
}
?>
```

It works perfectly! BUT
It changes the actual image on my server! Pretty cool, but not possible...

Obviously I cant change the image on Soundcloud's server (all the data, images, music comes from there API)

So What I'm looking for is a way were I can change the colour of the PNG client side, on the fly. I have a lot of tracks on there, so basically each time the user clicks next or previous, the waveform loads in and before it does it needs to change that image's colour :-?

Is this possible?

To see the player in action on my test site
(the styling on that one is old, by the way, but it's functionality is correct)
http://marckremers.com/2011/
NB the entire site does not work beyond what you see there. Still a WIP.

Thanks so much

Comment: What exactly is your goal? I can tell, by reading the things you've tried, but you would get better answers by clarifying this.

Comment: Since you are not actually searching for a PHP solution then, you should retag it for `javascript` and/or `css`. Besides canvas trickery, there might be other methods or simply jquery plugins (and e.g. MSIE has some awful css attributes for that).

Comment: Thanks Martijn, I made the change to the question

Comment: @Mario Hi, but i'm wondering if it is possible with PHP GD? Do you think this will be more of a CSS/Canvas/JS thing? Can you actually manipulate images with JS? Thanks

Comment: Well there is no client-side GD. You can certainly send the image over AJAX and transform it via PHP. But that wouldn't quite qualify as `client-side` anymore ;)

Answer (score 2):

This would have to be done client-side using Javascript, either a fully JS solution or one that uses AJAX to send it to PHP, then receives the final image.

You can try the Pixastic JS library:
http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/#intro

If that doesn't work, I would use jQuery to read the image, send it to a PHP script using JSRS/AJAX and then replace it on the page.

Comment: 11 years later, the link appears to be for an online gambling site...